# AWS Tutorial Code - Lambda Access Denied, incorrect server location showing in error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS and have only just started learning it. I am following [AWS's full-stack tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-web-app-s3-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb/module-four/), however, when I test module 4, my lambda function is not authorized to perform dynamodb:PutItem. In the error message, I can see the ARN has us-east-1 in it, however, the ARN I passed into the JSON for the IAM policy is eu-west-2. I have set everything up on eu-west-2 servers.

Here is the JSON used in the IAM policy, I have replaced my ID with xxxxx, but it is the same as what's listed in the table details on the DynamoDB dashboard.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:table/HelloWorldDatabase/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anything I should be checking elsewhere they could be wrong?

EDIT:

Having changed some JSON from comments, JSON now looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListAndDescribe",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SpecificTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/HelloWorldDatabase"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the full stack trace I am now getting:

```
Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: S62KLPBAGKNLA66SSI77RC1AC7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5110)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5077)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executePutItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2721)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.putItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2687)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PutItemImpl.doPutItem(PutItemImpl.java:85)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PutItemImpl.putItem(PutItemImpl.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.putItem(Table.java:168)
    at com.example.app.SavePersonHandler.persistData(SavePersonHandler.java:38)
    at com.example.app.SavePersonHandler.handleRequest(SavePersonHandler.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

From DynamoDB this is the table details:

Region  EU (London)
Amazon Resource Name (ARN)  arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:table/HelloWorldDatabase

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the `region` name  3rd module step named [Create a WebApp With Amplify Console](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-web-app-s3-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb/module-one/)

quoting from the above step:

> 4. In a new browser window, log into the Amplify Console. NOTE: We will be using the Oregon (us-west-2) region for this tutorial.

Please use the [Amazon DynamoDB: Allows access to a specific table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html)

> Below policy shows how you might create a policy that allows full access to the HelloWorldDatabase DynamoDB table. This policy grants the permissions necessary to complete this action from the AWS API or AWS CLI only.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListAndDescribe",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SpecificTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxx:table/HelloWorldDatabase"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have added this now however I am still getting this:  errorMessage": "Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;

Comment: @Kieran can you check manually in the console for the table arn and share the full stacktrace from the lambda. I am assuming you are copy/pasting the code  for lambda from the post you linked fo r

Comment: Updated original post with the extras

Comment: @Kieran unfortunately seems like the region name is hardcoded inside the jar. I could not read all of it as those are class files.  That's the reason even with correct policy you, it is throwing error because it is checking in the wrong region which seems to me from the decompiled jar is <US-EAST-1> or something else but not <EU-WEST-2> . I am assuming you have made sure the lambda role has the above policy attached.

Comment: Yes, I have attached the JAR to the lambda. I was suspicious it could have been hardcoded into the JAR. So if I wrote my own JAR for the lambda with the correct region then it should work in theory?

Comment: @Kieran region name in the code is ```US-WEST-2```. Updated the post.

Comment: @Kieran if this helps can you mark this as resolved. This helps the community and anyone who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to build Lambda functions that interact with AWS Services, such as Amazon DynamoDB, you can use the Lambda Java runtime API. This gives you full control exactly what you want the Lambda function to perform.

To interact with the AWS Services, you have to use an IAM role (as discussed in this tutorial). For example, to use DynamoDB, the IAM role has to have a policy that lets it use Amazon DynamoDB.

All of these concepts are covered in this API development tutorial. In addition, this tutorial shows you how to schedule the Lambda function using scheduled events:

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. To solve the issue, please use only usa-east-1 server along the way when doing the tutorial. The jar file seems to hard-code the server address.